# Can anyone tell me why the following regex won't match to "2015"?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string str = @"(?<Year>\d{4})?";
Regex regex = new Regex(str);
var match = regex.Match("abc/2015/01/11/efg_20150111.tsv");
```

I cannot find "2015" in match.Groups.
Thanks!

Comment: use `regex.Matches` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make the named capturing group  as optional.

```
@"(?<=\/)(?<Year>\d{4})(?=\/)"
```

OR

```
@"\b(?<Year>\d{4})\b"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dW8mK5/5)

`(?<Year>\d{4})?` matches an optional 4 digit number. `?` after the named capturing group makes the whole group as optional. And also add word boundaries , so that it won't a 4 digit number from `20150111`

```
string input = "abc/2015/01/11/efg_20150111.tsv";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\b(?<Year>\d{4})\b");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ANuByC)

Answer (score 3):

That's because your regular expression is optional.`(?<Year>\d{4})?` says, "Match 4 consecutive digits, **or nothing**. Nothing is still a match, as a small test program demonstrates:

```
Regex  rx = new Regex( @"(?<Year>\d{4})?");
Match m = rx.Match("abc/2015/01/11/efg_20150111.tsv");
int i = 0 ;

while ( m.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine( "match #{0}: +{1}({2}) is '{3}'." ,
    ++i , m.Index , m.Length , m.Value ) ;
  m = m.NextMatch();
}
if ( i == 0 )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "No matches");
}
```

The above finds the zero-length match pretty much everywhere it looks as its output shows:

```
match #1: +0(0) is ''.
match #2: +1(0) is ''.
match #3: +2(0) is ''.
match #4: +3(0) is ''.
match #5: +4(4) is '2015'.
match #6: +8(0) is ''.
match #7: +9(0) is ''.
match #8: +10(0) is ''.
match #9: +11(0) is ''.
match #10: +12(0) is ''.
match #11: +13(0) is ''.
match #12: +14(0) is ''.
match #13: +15(0) is ''.
match #14: +16(0) is ''.
match #15: +17(0) is ''.
match #16: +18(0) is ''.
match #17: +19(4) is '2015'.
match #18: +23(4) is '0111'.
match #19: +27(0) is ''.
match #20: +28(0) is ''.
match #21: +29(0) is ''.
match #22: +30(0) is ''.
match #23: +31(0) is ''.
```

That's the way regular expression engines work.